# transferring bytes from one ByteBuffer to another

Tags: java, javadoc, nio

What's the most efficient way to put as many bytes as possible from a ByteBuffer `bbuf_src` into another ByteBuffer `bbuf_dest` (as well as know how many bytes were transferred)? I'm trying `bbuf_dest.put(bbuf_src)` but it seems to want to throw a BufferOverflowException and I can't get the javadocs from Sun right now (network problems) when I need them. >:(  argh.

---

edit: darnit, @Richard's approach (use put() from the backing array of `bbuf_src`) won't work if bbuf_src is a ReadOnly buffer, as you can't get access to that array. What can I do in that case???

Comment: I think you should break this into two questions.

Comment: the other half has been relocated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570218/downloading-sun-javadocs-mirror-websites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've adapted @Richard's answer:

```
public static int transferAsMuchAsPossible(
                     ByteBuffer bbuf_dest, ByteBuffer bbuf_src)
{
  int nTransfer = Math.min(bbuf_dest.remaining(), bbuf_src.remaining());
  if (nTransfer > 0)
  {
    bbuf_dest.put(bbuf_src.array(), 
                  bbuf_src.arrayOffset()+bbuf_src.position(), 
                  nTransfer);
    bbuf_src.position(bbuf_src.position()+nTransfer);
  }
  return nTransfer;
}
```

and a test to make sure it works:

```
public static boolean transferTest()
{
    ByteBuffer bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);
    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(50);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        bb1.put((byte)i);
    }
    bb1.flip();
    bb1.position(5);
    ByteBuffer bb1a = bb1.slice();
    bb1a.position(2);
    // bb3 includes the 5-100 range
    bb2.put((byte)77);
    // something to see this works when bb2 isn't empty
    int n = transferAsMuchAsPossible(bb2, bb1a);
    boolean itWorked = (n == 49);

    if (bb1a.position() != 51)
        itWorked = false;
    if (bb2.position() != 50)
        itWorked = false;
    bb2.rewind();
    if (bb2.get() != 77)
        itWorked = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 49; ++i)
    {
        if (bb2.get() != i+7)
        {
            itWorked = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return itWorked;
}
```

Comment: This won't work for copying from a read-only `ByteBuffer`, as `.array()` is not allowed (there's unfortunately no such thing as a read-only array in Java).

Answer (score 11):

As you've discovered, getting the backing array doesn't always work (it fails for read only buffers, direct buffers, and memory mapped file buffers).  The better alternative is to duplicate your source buffer and set a new limit for the amount of data you want to transfer:

```
int maxTransfer = Math.min(bbuf_dest.remaining(), bbuf_src.remaining());
// use a duplicated buffer so we don't disrupt the limit of the original buffer
ByteBuffer bbuf_tmp = bbuf_src.duplicate ();
bbuf_tmp.limit (bbuf_tmp.position() + maxTransfer);
bbuf_dest.put (bbuf_tmp);

// now discard the data we've copied from the original source (optional)
bbuf_src.position(bbuf_src.position() + maxTransfer);
```

Comment: But Oracle says that limit must be "no larger than buffer's capacity". Duplicating a buffer will duplicate its capacity, isn't it?

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but why duplicate the source buffer instead of just storing the old limit and restoring it after the put operation?

Comment: @Wisteso - you could do that, and it may be slightly more efficient (although not a lot, so in most situations it's unlikely to matter), but I think it's easier to duplicate the buffer.  And harder to get it wrong (e.g. by forgetting to restore afterwards).

Comment: @Jules Thank you for the feedback. I've modified my code to save/restore the limit and its working really well. I didn't want to duplicate it due to the very high throughput + GC burden. I also needed the changes to 'position' to be permanent.

Answer (score 0):

You get the BufferOverflowException because your bbuf_dest is not big enough.

You will need to use bbuf_dest.remaining() to find out the maximum number of bytes you can transfer from bbuf_src:

```
int maxTransfer = Math.min(bbuf_dest.remaining(), bbuf_src.remaining());
bbuf_dest.put(bbuf_src.array(), 0, maxTransfer);
```

Comment: Ah. That's helpful. I think I know what to do now. Thanks. But note that your answer won't work if bbuf_src is a view buffer for another buffer. I think I can adapt it though.

Comment: (or if bbuf_src's position is > 0)