# Google Project Tango: Why does my pointcloud get displayed only along x, y and z axis?

Tags: point-clouds, google-project-tango

I am trying to edit the point cloud (stored in a FloatBuffer) in order to keep recorded points on the screen. However, when I display the points, they all lie on the x, y or z axis. I am using the example Point Cloud program from Google, and so all I'm doing right now is copying the buffer so I can edit it since the current buffer is read-only. I haven't changed anything else since I need to get my copy to work first. Here is my code for copying the buffer (edited from [transferring bytes from one ByteBuffer to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570168/transferring-bytes-from-one-bytebuffer-to-another)):

```
private FloatBuffer cloneBuffer(FloatBuffer original) {
    final ByteBuffer byteClone = (original.isDirect()) ?
            //multiplied by 4 and added 3 so the capacity would be the
            //same when converted to a FloatBuffer
            ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(original.capacity() * 4 + 3) :
            ByteBuffer.allocate(original.capacity() * 4 + 3);

    final FloatBuffer clone = byteClone.asFloatBuffer();
    final FloatBuffer readOnlyCopy = original.asReadOnlyBuffer();

    readOnlyCopy.rewind();
    clone.put(readOnlyCopy);
    clone.flip();
    clone.position(original.position());


    return clone;
}
```

Comment: Could you make sure the shader for your render is loaded correctly? I noticed that the gl context is needed even when you allocate the PointCloud (loading the shader in constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at: 
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/known-issues

In the "Depth" section, notice that:

- The IJ buffer of the XYZij struct is under development and not yet populated via the API.
- Occasionally, or when under high CPU load, the depth flash may appear in the color image, or no depth points are returned. Let the device cool down and/or reboot.

Your problem may lie within the first mentioned point.