# How to copy partially one byteBuffer to another one without byteBuffer.array()

Tags: java, copy, slice, bytebuffer, unsupportedoperation

I have an empty byteBuffer allocated as

`data = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(layerSize(0, faces - 1, 0, levels - 1) * layers);`

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/570261/1047713), I tried to use the `array()` method as following

```
public void setData(ByteBuffer data, int layer, int face, int level) {
    int offset = offset(layer, face, level);
    int levelSize = levelSize(level);
    this.data.put(data.array(), offset, levelSize);
}
```

But I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.array(ByteBuffer.java:994)
```

The source bytebuffer I am trying to use is read in this way:

```
    File file = new File(Load.class.getResource(fileName).getFile());
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();

    return loadKtx(fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, (int) file.length()));

public static Texture loadKtx(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) throws IOException {
    ...
                byteBuffer.position(offset);
                byteBuffer.limit(offset + faceSize);

                ByteBuffer data = byteBuffer.slice();
                texture.setData(data, layer, face, level);

                byteBuffer.position(0);
                byteBuffer.limit(byteBuffer.capacity());
```

Is there a better option than a simple

```
    for (int b = 0; b < levelSize; b++) {
        this.data.put(offset + b, data.get(b));
    }
```

?

However, whole project [here](https://github.com/elect86/jgli/tree/master/Jgli/src/jgli) for who is interested.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put-java.nio.ByteBuffer-

Comment: @StephenC, I need to copy the byteBuffer by specifing an offset and a length

Comment: Then there is no better method.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with ```this.data.put(data.array(), offset, levelSize);```? You want to copy a portion of a ByteBuffer into itself?

Comment: @StephenC, if you want to answer that I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like there is not.

Credits to @Stefen C

Comment: Stephen faenfen

Answer (score 6):

Are you just trying to copy a portion of one `ByteBuffer` into another? If so, you should `duplicate()` the `ByteBuffer` you want to copy, set the `position` and `limit` of the duplicated buffer to the range you'd like to copy, then use `put()`. Like:

```
ByteBuffer src = data.duplicate();
src.position(offset);
src.limit(offset + levelSize);
dest.put(src);
```

Comment: I'd like to copy an entire byteBuffer into another by an offset

Comment: Instead of `duplicate()` I would prefer the `slice()` method as it allows to let the new ByteBuffer start at the current position.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this:

```
ByteBuffer src = //...
byte[] remaining = new byte[src.capacity() - src.position() /*or offset */];
src.get(remaining);
ByteBuffer dest = ByteBuffer.wrap(remaining);
```